# Configuring a LAN with two wireless routers

Tags: router, wireless-networking, setup

I have two wireless routers. Can I make them transparent to each other?

example.

Router A is the one connected to the internet.

Router B is the one up stairs, connected to the printer.

When I'm wirelessly connected to Router A can I access the printer on Router B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a cable connecting to the two routers?

If so, just plug the cable into one of the LAN jacks on router B, and configure it to be on the same subnet as router A, just give it a different IP address. Also, be sure to turn off the DHCP server on the router.

Example:

WAN (internet) -> Router A -> Cable from LAN A to LAN B -> Router B -> Printer attached to LAN B

Router A IP Address: 192.168.1.1
Router B IP Address: 192.168.1.2

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure Router B to act as a bridge so all devices are on the same subnet.

Exactly how to do that (and whether it can be done at all) depends on the router. You might be able to using the stock firmware, but it's not likely (especially if the router has been provided by your ISP). If your router is supported, switching to [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) or [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) should work.